# Divide one bin2d by another bin2d to generate a new bin2d plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data.frames x and y. I am interested in the change of relations between "A" and "B" from x to y. So, I plot bin2d plot "A" and "B" using geom_bin2d for x and y separately. But, it's hard to find the difference between two bin2d plots.

```
ggplot(X1, aes_string("factor_1", "factor_2")) + geom_bin2d(aes(fill = ..density..)) + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red", "blue"))
ggplot(X2, aes_string("factor_1", "factor_2")) + geom_bin2d(aes(fill = ..density..)) + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red", "blue"))
```

Is there a way to do (bin2d_x / bin2d_y) or (bin2d_x - bin2d_y), and then plot the difference?

Test code to illustrate the situation:

```
X1 <- data.frame( class = "a", "factor_1" = rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 1), "factor_2" = rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd =1))
X2 <- data.frame( class = "b", "factor_1" = rnorm(5000, mean = 3, sd = 1), "factor_2" = rnorm(5000, mean = 3, sd =1))
ggplot(rbind(X1, X2), aes_string("factor_1", "factor_2")) + geom_bin2d(aes(fill = ..density..)) + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red", "blue"))
```

But, class variable cannot be properly shown in the graph.

Comment: Make your colors transparent.

Comment: But, with transparent color, I still don't know which part has more x than y.

Comment: How to make two layers of geom_bin2D() ?

Comment: Extra data arguments in aes()?

Comment: I add color = class in aes(), but it does not add another layer. I guess two geom_bin2d is necessary, but it just overwrite the existing geom_bin2d..

Comment: `data` , not `color`.

Comment: data is not an argument in aes().

Comment: It overwrites the previous plot. Only the last one is left.

Comment: Since you have provided no data object for testing I suspect the level of interest in guessing the correct approach will be small.

Comment: Please check the new post for data of testing.